# Custom Rules Actions to set content to unpublished

Tags: 8, rules

Is there a way to write a custom Rules Action with this conditions.

> **Default**: Content Type X is set to create unpublished content.

**RULES**

> **Event**: After saving new content
>
> **Condition**: when a content of type X is created
>
> **Action**: ***Set status to published***

Answer (score 2):

Even though your Rules question could be like an exercise for a training session like "Getting started with Rules in D7", the most recent release of Rules for D8 (= [Alfa 3](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/releases/8.x-3.0-alpha3)) does not support this yet.

However, as a work-around, you could implement the very same logic if you'd adapt the configuration of your content type X so that the default is that newly created content is published right away.

**Note**: if your goal is to "*let anonymous users access unpublished contents*" (as in your comment below this answer), then the [view_unpublished](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_unpublished) module could be a possible alternative. As per its project page: it allows you to grant access for specific user roles to view unpublished nodes of a specific type.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Yes, I understand that. My goal is just to let anonymous users access unpublished contents. But it seems I cant achieve it by setting the view with permissions so I was thinking of Rules. I actually found this module *view_unpublished* that solves my problem.